# Getting the parent element of the text near the cursor-Caret

Tags: javascript, html

For example:
page has some paragraphs with text:

```
<p>some text1</p>
<p>some text2</p>
<p>some text3</p>
```

so the browser will render:

some text1
some text2
some text3

Now, if user places the Caret, lets say on text2 (between 't' and 'e' ,document is in designmode=on), the function should return  ref to the second p object.

I think it should be done using range object...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the even of the editable box such as focus event and use the **this** keyword to get it's reference.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered adding onHover listeners to all the elements you might need to know if the mouse is over? Using jQuery (very basic example)

```
var currentHover = null;
$('p').hover(function(){
    currentHover = this;
},
function(){
    currentHover = null
});
```

Comment: the paragraphs are added to page dynamically, on run time

Comment: and i not need it on hover, only when cursor is placed (edit mode)